# Chain rule partial derivatives: show that $\frac{\partial R}{\partial t} = -V \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Problem statement:** Let $R(x,t)$ remain steady in time: that is, $R(x,t) = R(s)$, where $s = x - Vt$. Using the chain rule, show that the rain rate at a fixed point evolves as:

$$\frac{\partial R}{\partial t} = -V \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}.$$

**My attempt at a solution:** So, I have found a chain rule that says that if $z = f(s,r)$, $s = g(x,t)$, $r = h(x,t)$, then

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s } \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial t}.$$

However, when I try to apply this to my problem, I keep ending up with: $z = R$, $f = s$, $s = x-Vt$, $r = 0$, so

$$\frac{\partial R}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial t}  = \frac{\partial R}{\partial s} (-V).$$

So, I'm taking the partial with respect to the wrong variable, somehow :( What am I doing wrong? Assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $R(x,t) = R(s)$ unless $s=(x,t)$.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what that means, either, since that's just exactly what is written in the problem statement. I was assuming that it means that $R$ is a function of $s$, which is a function of $x$ and $t$, but I guess I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what it i meant to be. I assume the wave equation, or one solution thereof, but that's a guess.

Comment: For example, if $R(s+Vt,t)$ is a constant, then you can obtain the above equation using the chain rule.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think that my professor meant for $R(s + Vt, t)$ to be constant - I should have mentioned that in the post, but it was in part (a) of this problem, and I didn't think it applied to this part, for some reason. Thanks! Please feel free to make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\rho(t)=R(s+Vt,t)$ is constant, then ${d \rho(t) \over dt} = 0$. The
chain rule gives
${d \rho(t) \over dt} = {\partial R(s+Vt,t) \over \partial x} V + {\partial R(s+Vt,t) \over \partial t} = 0$, which is the desired result.